# Comparing datatables / identify identical datatables

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I am working with VB.net and mysql, I have a function which fills a datatable with mysql content then posts it (as appropriate) to a listview. This function is currently on a timer which activates every 5 seconds which unfortunately does horrible destruction to the drag-and-drop features of my software.

The solution: I have decided after filling the content to the listview to copy the content from the active datatable to another datatable for comparison, every time the data is taken from the mysql db have it save to a datatable and compare the two datatables - if they are not identical the software should run the function however if they are identical there is no reason to update the listview with the same exact data.

```
    Public pendrun As New DataTable
    Public postrun As New DataTable

   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;" _
& "user id=user;" _
& "password=password;" _
& "database=DMT"
    adptr = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from data", con)
    Try
        adptr.Fill(pendrun)
    Catch err As Exception
        Dim strError As String = "Exception: & err.ToString()"
    End Try
if pendrun <> postrun then
    ListView2.Items.Clear()
    pendrun.Clear()

' commands to add
' pendrun datatable information
' to listview

postrun = pendrun 'to transfer data to the holding datatable

end if
```

the problem is

```
if pendrun <> postrun then
```

is not a valid way to compare datatables.
How do I identify if the datatables are identical (all rows and columns identical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the resulting code I created to deal with this problem - thanks to David for the direction

```
Function TablesAreEqual(ByVal firstTable As DataTable, ByVal secondTable As DataTable) As Boolean
dim db1 As String = ""
dim db2 As String = ""
    For rown As Integer = 0 To firstTable.Rows.Count - 1
        For cown As Integer = 0 To firstTable.Columns.Count - 1
            db1 = db1 & firstTable.Rows(rown).Item(cown)
        Next
    Next
    For rown As Integer = 0 To secondTable.Rows.Count - 1
        For cown As Integer = 0 To secondTable.Columns.Count - 1
            db2 = db2 & secondTable.Rows(rown).Item(cown)
        Next
    Next
    Return db1 = db2

 End Function
```

Comment: So inefficient.  Why would u build up every row and column if the first row and column did not match?   String is immutable - db1 = db1 & is very inefficient.  Why not start with testing row count as I suggested in my answer.  And without a sort you could have the same rows but in a different order.  If you are going to write the whole thing out then why not use WriteXml as suggested by Milani?

Comment: As I stated I am pulling from a mysql db - in my situation I am using an order command so in fact if the order changes it will be a big deal and worthy of a renewal of the listview - any change whatsoever needs to be addressed - I was tossing code, with what I already know how to do, to come to a solution which works for my application, I would rather build up my entire string which in my scenario will never be more than approximately 2500 characters than add the additional procedure of searching every single row, also I developed my solution without internet connection - never saw your post

Comment: What additional procedure of searching every single row?  The code you have now accesses every column and every row.  The code you have now does an equity comparison.   U could do this right with less lines of code than u have now.  And there is no sort in your problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in understanding of "identical" for types you've defined.  You'll need to write that logic.

Essentially you need to build a function which accepts two `DataTable`s as input, compares them in accordance with whatever business logic you define, and returns a `Boolean` indicating whether or not they pass that logic.  Something like this:

```
Function TablesAreEqual(ByVal firstTable As DataTable, ByVal secondTable As DataTable) As Boolean 
    ' Compare your tables, probably by looping through rows/values
    Return areEqual
End Function
```

Then you'd use that function in your comparison:

```
If TablesAreEqual(pendrun, postrun) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your pendrun and postrun datatables
try to serialize "writeXml" datatables and compare them.

Anyway i suggest you to think about a different approach instead of using a polling timer.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet why not put in logic to not get new data if it has not changed.
Don't know about MySQL but MSSQL has Notification and TimeStamp

The columns should only change with a schema change.
First compare count and if not the same for sure there was a change.
If counts are the same then loop through the columns and compare.
As soon as one does not compare then done immediately return false.

On rows same thing.   First test row count.
After that need to compare row by row and column by column.
Remember to sort the select statement so you would catch rows out of order.
And again as soon as one does not compare stop and return false.

Right with less code than you have in your answer
My inserts are C#

```
Function TablesAreEqual(ByVal firstTable As DataTable, ByVal secondTable As DataTable) As Boolean
    if(firstTable.Rows.Count != secondTable.Rows.Count) return false;
    if(firstTable.Columns.Count != secondTable.Columns.Count) return false;
    For rown As Integer = 0 To firstTable.Rows.Count - 1
        For cown As Integer = 0 To firstTable.Columns.Count - 1
            if (firstTable.Rows(rown).Item(cown) != secondTable.Rows(rown).Item(cown)) return false;
        Next
    Next
    return true;   
 End Function
```